# SpriteBatch being drawn outside of Stage?

Tags: libgdx, spritebatch

Currently working on my first game, though running into some problems with libgx and screen aspect ratio.

What I have is a Stage which contains things like menu buttons etc, and the rest of the game is pretty much sprites being drawn with via SpriteBatch. To avoid having multiple SpriteBatches and cameras, I have re-used the ones that are created when Stage is created.

```
    stage = new Stage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, true); // keep aspect ratio
    batch = stage.getSpriteBatch();
    camera = (OrthographicCamera) stage.getCamera();
    // move camera so 'active' screen is centred
    stage.getCamera().translate(-stage.getGutterWidth(), -stage.getGutterHeight(), 0);
```

Anything that is Stage/Actor related is drawn fine - all goes within the aspect ratio adjusted boundaries.

The problem I'm having is anything that drawn via SpriteBatch, seems to ignore this viewport that is defined by Stage and can be visible outside of the Stage area.

```
batch.begin();
...
sirWuffles.draw(batch);
...
batch.end();
```

For example, in the above, if Sir Wuffles is generated outside of the defined WIDTH/HEIGHT it might still appear in the "gutters" of the screen.

Tried to explain it in the below screenshot. It's an exaggerated screen ratio to make the gutters large. I've also covered most of the gutter area in the blue/cyan rectangle so they are very obvious.

[image: screenshot]

Does anyone know what is happening? and how to fix it?

Currently, my "fix" is to use ShapeRenderer to draw rectangles that correspond to the gutters on top of the sprites...

Comment: Could you show us the code that you use to set position of your sprites, because 0,0 is not the bottom left corner of your stage but of your screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually apply the stage's projection, defined by the camera, to the batch before rendering as such:

```
batch.setProjectionMatrix(stage.getCamera().combined);
```

Also remember to call `camera.update()` after you change the camera's position, which will update the projection matrix.

You gotta think about the `SpriteBatch` as its own separate entity for `Stage`, in that you shouldn't expect anything you do to the `Stage` to have an effect on the `SpriteBatch` when used in another context, such as manual batch rendering in your case.

Comment: Initially had this and gave it another go. Still no good. Sprites are still being drawn "off camera" :(

Answer (score 0):

```
public void resize(int width, int height) {

     Vector2 size = Scaling.fit.apply(FIXED_STAGE_WIDTH,FIXED_STAGE_HEIGHT, width, height);
        int viewportX = (int)(width - size.x) / 2;
        int viewportY = (int)(height - size.y) / 2;
        int viewportWidth = (int)size.x;
        int viewportHeight = (int)size.y;
        Gdx.gl.glViewport(viewportX, viewportY, viewportWidth, viewportHeight);
        stage.setViewport(FIXED_STAGE_WIDTH, FIXED_STAGE_HEIGHT, true, viewportX, viewportY, viewportWidth, viewportHeight);
}
```

This should do the trick for you. Here the drawing outside the stage is not possible.

Comment: This answer could be improved with an explanation of why that works.